# Sql Query for FINDING 98th OR 99th element from given 100 numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a SQL Query for finding 98th or 99th element from given 100 numbers.

Comment: Please clarify your question, possibly include the column names in your table and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: could you be more unclear

Answer (score 0):

Just use `offset` and `limit`.  For the 99th number:

```
select n
from numbers
order by n
limit 98, 1;
```

Comment: Select * from Tablename
where count id=99

is this possible??

Comment: Nope.  That is not valid SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `daily_report` limit 97,2
```

this will give you two records of 98 and 99

Comment: Select * from Tablename where count id=99 is this possible??

Comment: This give you all the record which have the count_id as 99 not the 98th or 99th no. of record ie if there is not count_id 99 then it return no result, but if there is the record on 99 auto increment id then it will show the record